# Should I care about big-endian machines while using Uint32Array

Tags: javascript, endianness, arraybuffer

Should I care about big-endian machines while using `Uint32Array` and other `TypedArray`s that represent more than 1 byte array?

Are there devices with big-endian architecture that can correctly open modern sites that use ArrayBuffer API? How much?

[All Android devices are little-endian.](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html) I assume that AMD and Intel based computers too.

---

For example, for little-endian:

```js
const buffer = new TextEncoder().encode("abcd").buffer; // It's [97, 98, 99, 100] bytes
new Uint32Array(buffer); // [1684234849]

new Uint32Array(new Uint8Array([0, 0, 0, 1]).buffer); // [16777216]
new Uint32Array(new Uint8Array([1, 0, 0, 0]).buffer); // [1]
```

But I assume that on the big-endian machine I will get the other results: `[1633837924]`, `[1]` and `[16777216]` correspondingly.

---

Also I can note that bitwise operations works transparancy with `TypeArray`s, as if I just work with `Number` (big-endian).

```js
new Uint32Array(new Uint8Array([0, 0, 0, 1]).buffer)[0] >> 16; // 256
16777216 >> 16; // 256
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're concerned about endianness, you can use the [`DataView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView) interface. This allows you to assert the endianness of a byte array, rather than relying on the platform byte order.

This may be a concern if you expect your code to run on a PowerPC platform like an XBox or PS3.

Comment: DataView is unfortunately slower than TypedArray views, for performance sensitive operations writing two versions of a same function might be preferred.